# $state.go doesn't work with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When an item is clicked, its path is sent as parameter to `state` function and the state function does `$state.go` to load a state with the passed path as parameter.

This doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

## Template

`<div  ng-click="state(item.class, item.path, item.mime_type)">`

## Controller

```js
controller("groupsListCtrl", ["$scope", "handler", "$state",
  function($scope, handler, $state) {
    handler.get("/home").then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response;
      $scope.items = $scope.data.inventory;

      $scope.state = function(stateType, objectPath, mimeType) {
        $state.go("workarea.user", {
          path: objectPath
        });
      }
    })
  }
])
```

## Router

```js
.state("workarea.user", {
  url: "^/workarea/:path",
  requireLogin: true,
  views: {
    "options": {
      templateUrl: "/views/options.html",
      controller: "optionsCtrl"
    },
    "workspace": {
      templateUrl: "/views/workspace.html",
      controller: "workspaceCtrl"
    },
    "comments": {
      templateUrl: "/views/comments.html",
      controller: "commentsCtrl"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`handler.get("/home").then(function(response) {` looks like a promise to me.
Try moving `$scope.state` definition outside this promise.

```
controller("groupsListCtrl", ["$scope", "handler", "$state",
  function($scope, handler, $state) {
    handler.get("/home").then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response;
      $scope.items = $scope.data.inventory;
    });

    $scope.state = function(stateType, objectPath, mimeType) {
      $state.go("workarea.user", {
        path: objectPath
      });
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: It is a promise. But this solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you move `$scope.state` outside the promise?

Comment: Yes. the function is moved out of the promise. No luck, though.

Comment: this's strange. Can you create a plunker/fiddle with your code?